# How can I change a string into a date in Liquid?

Tags: liquid

I have strings like `09011990` that I would like to display as `September 1, 1990` in my Liquid templates.

I previously used `{{widgets.Date.Digits | split:"" | join:" , "}}` for another field where I would get all my digits separated, but I'm unable to find a way where I can separate digits in terms of 2 digits for month, 2 for the day and 4 for the year and then use a `/` in between so that it can be clearly distinguished as a date.

Comment: I've tried several techniques, but cannot find a way to cast a string to an actual date (or time) object in Liquid. I think the only way is to use string functions to operate on your string, as the only answer explains below.

Answer (score 1):

If you know that your "date digits" will always be in the same order, you can use the `slice` filter to assign different parts of the number to variables. For example, say we have the date coming in as a variable called `date_digits`:

```
{%- assign month = date_digits | slice: 0, 2 %}
{%- assign day   = date_digits | slice: 2, 2 %}
{%- assign year  = date_digits | slice: 4, 4 %}
```

Then we can use `capture` to combine all three values into a string that's parseable by the `date` filter. From my testing, the `date` filter really prefers the order day, month, year:

```
{%- capture date_string %}{{ day }}/{{ month }}/{{ year }}{%- endcapture %}
```

Finally, we can use the `date` filter to display our human-readable date:

```
{{ date_string | date: "%B %d, %Y" }}
```

Produces `September 01, 1990`.

This is a pretty fragile solution, but it's possible using just Liquid.